# Download / Save a whole question with all answers and comments?

Tags: support

Is is possible to download a whole question together with all answers and comments?

Of course it is possible to use the "save" function of the browser. But then you need to open up all comments and browse through all pages.

Therefore, I mean something more broader. Like something which could be used for directly creating a pretty formatted PDF document.

Or like saving all the data which is stored alongside with the question in the Stackoverflow database. (In that case, even the edits could be included!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) for that

or if you want to have more control over what to fetch you can use [this SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/332079?postid=11227809) and export the results to an CSV file and post-process that result.

This [answer of mine on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269951/158100) elaborates a bit how to create an html page of all content.

Or if you need data for attribute purposes use [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261594/158100)

Comment: Oooooh didn't know any of them! That's both pretty nice !! **Yes, that's it!** Thanks!

Comment: Always good to see a happy customer ;)

Comment: Can you take a look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335565/is-there-any-browser-extension-addon-or-easy-way-to-download-all-your-favorite-q) and answer the question. I looked into your other answers and am trying to figure it out, but it could take me forever to learn. I'm just a newbie Swift developer...