# Is there a way to download questions of a particular tag?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there any way to download questions of a particular tag?

Like, I am interested to save some highly voted questions as PDF in any tag, and I would like to fetch all the comments and answers related to that question for offline access.

How can I download/save the high voted questions instead of bookmarking it?

Comment: you can setup an [rss feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags) of your favorite tag..Also see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105945/stackoverflow-feed-on-specified-tags) .

Comment: Related: [Download / Save a whole question with all answers and comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298556/2675154)